# theming form of block subscription newsletter module

Tags: theming

someone could tell me how to form theming block newsletter subscription module,
I use the bootstrap theme and I want to change the markup and add some classes css

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. One is this way to [theme the blocks](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/theming-blocks).

There is simpler way to add a [class to a block](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class) then add css in the theme info file.

Comment: Thanks was looking for a solution that was the way of theming the HTML and CSS through bootstrap template